# Procedure Error when creating a pivot table using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

When I run the below VBA code to create a pivot table, I get an "Invalid procedure or call argument error" when running the macro.  The error is on the "Set PT" area.

I've defined worksheet objects but I also tried adjusting the "Table Destination" to directly reference the worksheet and I still get the same error.

Any idea what might be causing the error?

```
With wsData
    Dim PTCache As PivotCache
    Dim PT As PivotTable

    'Creates the Cache
    Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
        SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=.Range("A1").CurrentRegion)

    'Creates pivot table
    Set PT = wsPivot.PivotTables.Add( _
        PivotCache:=PTCache, _
        TableDestination:=wsPivot)

    'Defines fields
    With PT
        .PivotFields("Field 1").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("Field 2").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("Field 3").Orientation = xlRowField
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Field 4"), "Field 4", xlCount
        .TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium2"
    End With
End With
```

Comment: What's `wsPivot`?

Comment: Its a worksheet object, equal to something like '[Worksheet.xlsm]Sheets("Pivot")'

Comment: `TableDestination` argument requires a specified range. See [PivotTables.Add Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivottables-add-method-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks.  Based off that information I tweaked that section to be:

        Set PT = wsPivot.PivotTables.Add( _
            PivotCache:=PTCache, _
            TableDestination:=wsPivot.Range("A3"), _
            TableName:="Pivot Table")

I still got the same error : "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument"

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, rather than building the pivot cache from the `ActiveWorkbook` I used `ThisWorkbook` instead.

The following code ran without error:

```
With wsData
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim PT As PivotTable

'Creates the Cache
Set PTCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=.Range("A1").CurrentRegion)

'Creates pivot table
Set PT = wsPivot.PivotTables.Add( _
    PivotCache:=PTCache, _
    TableDestination:=wsPivot)

'Defines fields
With PT
    .PivotFields("Field 1").Orientation = xlRowField
    .PivotFields("Field 2").Orientation = xlRowField
    .PivotFields("Field 3").Orientation = xlRowField
    .AddDataField .PivotFields("Field 4"), "Field 4", xlCount
    .TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium2"
End With
End With
```